# AVtouch problem

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

In my app, I select one song from tableView and played in default player, 
and then when i back to playlist (i.e tableview) and select another song
then BOTH songs played simultaneously.

How I solve this problem ? I want to play when another song select then that selected song must played and previous one should be stopped.

Please HELP.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray Problem solved....

Problem: Multiple songs overlapping in player.

Reason : Multiple instance creation of AVAudioPlayer.

Solution: Create only one instance at launch, and when play called
then [audioplayer stop] then play (using flags avoid multiple creation).

Thanx to all.